# Is there a more efficient way to find the coordinates surrounding a list of contiguous coordinates, without assuming the shape of the listed coords?

Tags: python, 2d, coordinates

I'm working on a level generator that builds tile-based rooms potentially of an irregular (non-rectangular) shape. I need to be able to identify the tiles outside the room that are adjacent to the room, so I can make them serve as the walls of the room. I have an approach that works, but seems inefficient as it involves checking every tile in the room, including ones that are fully interior to the room and therefore checking them will not contribute to finding tiles that need to become wall tiles. I am wondering if there is a better approach to the problem than what I am currently doing?

```
def find_room_wall_coords(room_coords):
    room_coords_set = set(room_coords)
    
    room_wall_coords_set = set()

    adjacent_positions = [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 1), (-1, -1), (1, -1), (-1, 1)]

    for x, y in room_coords:
        for dx, dy in adjacent_positions:
            adjacent_coord = (x + dx, y + dy)
            if adjacent_coord not in room_coords_set:
                room_wall_coords_set.add(adjacent_coord)

    return list(room_wall_coords_set)

room_coords_example = [(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3)]
room_wall_coords = find_room_wall_coords(room_coords_example)
room_wall_coords.sort()
print(room_wall_coords)
```

For the room_coords example in the code, this correctly prints:

(0, 0), (0, 1),  (0, 2),  (0, 3),  (0, 4),  (0, 5),  (1, 0),  (1, 5),  (2, 0),  (2, 4),  (2, 5),  (3, 0),  (3, 1),  (3, 2),  (3, 3),  (3, 4)

In the real code the coords refer to positions on a 2d numpy array, I don't think that is relevant but mentioning it anyway just in case.